# Sub Menu items not showing

Tags: navigation

I am trying to create a navigation with a sub-menu in Drupal 9. I added the top level nav item with and used # as the value for the link, and checked "Show as expanded"

Then I created a new item and chose the Top Level Item as the parent nav.

Top Level Item
Sub Item

On my menu now the Top Level Item has an arrow, but the sub item is not there. And in dev tools under inspector I do not see the code for the sub item.

Is there a step I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution here - https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2019-08-03/menu-item-children-not-rendered-in

I needed to change "Number of levels to display" under the Navigation block to Unlimited